# Is UL approval at all possible for low voltage USB and network LAN Cat6 patch cables

Tags: usb, cable-assemblies

I am from a European distributor. Some of our customers, who export to the US are asking for UL approved Cat6 and USB patch cables. Is it even possible to UL approve these low volatage cables? i.e is it only mains attached products that qualify for UL?

Comment: Why not get in contact with UL and ask them directly?

Comment: Google shows piles of ethernet cable with UL listing.  Also, it isn't just the voltage and insulation that is important.  Other things like flame resistance and I don't know what all come into play.  [Check with UL, they are online](http://ulstandards.ul.com/standards-catalog/?search=cable)

Comment: It also depends which UL process are you referring to, you can take your device, hand it with a list of instructions to UL and they will certify the outcome they see with that list of instructions.

Comment: UL also seems to have offices in many european countries.

Comment: Actually, American Electrical Code governs ethernet cables physically installed in a building or caravan, and requires UL listing or equivalent for those.  You certainly don't want to be in the business of certifying UL cable unless you are a cable manufacturer, just buy UL listed cable on the open market,

Answer (score 1):

There are UL Listed [Cat6 cable assemblies](http://www.telegaertner.com/en/infostream/patchkabel-ul/) and there is UL Listed [USB 3.0 cable](http://www.hca.hitachi-cable.com/products/hca/products/round/usb/usb-3-bulk-cable.php). However, the final cable products your customers desire are what need to be tested and certified. You should check with your suppliers to see what cable assemblies are offered by them that either are or could be UL approved under the standards desired by your customers.